# Does exportfs disrupt users already utilizing those filesystems?

Tags: configuration, filesystems, export, etc

I need to modify a servers /etc/exports file to export to an additional host.  After modifying this file, for it to take effect (i.e. for the additional host to have access to the designated filesystem), I believe I have to run "exportfs" on the server exporting the filesystem.  Does this disrupt users who are currently using filesystems that are exported from that serving host?  I'm hoping to add this new host "silently", without disruption.

Any additional advice related to this, common traps, things to be careful of, etc. would be appreciated if you have any.

Edit: just in case...uname -a returns 
**2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 2 17:04:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modification you made doesn't change the permissions for your current users, it should be non disruptive.  Use the `-r` flag for exportfs.  We do this all the time and existing, in-use mounts are unaffected.

From the man page:

```
       -r     Reexport all directories, synchronizing /var/lib/nfs/etab with /etc/exports.  This  option  removes  entries  in
          /var/lib/nfs/etab  which have been deleted from /etc/exports, and removes any entries from the kernel export ta-
          ble which are no longer valid.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I successfully used exportfs -r without disruption :)